# Mutable borrow in loop disallowed if wrapper type impls Drop

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Consider the following minimal example:

```rust
struct Wrapper<'a>(&'a mut i32);
impl<'a> Drop for Wrapper<'a> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {}
}
fn main() {
    let mut a = 0;
    let mut f = None;
    for _ in 0..100 {
        f = match f {
            None => Some(Wrapper(&mut a)),
            Some(a) => Some(a),
        };
    }
}
```

This produces the following compiler error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `a` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:10:34
   |
9  |         f = match f {
   |                   - first borrow used here, in later iteration of loop
10 |             None => Some(Wrapper(&mut a)),
   |                                  ^^^^^^ `a` was mutably borrowed here in the previous iteration of the loop
```

However, when removing the `Drop` implementation of `Wrapper` the snippet compiles just fine.

Is this a bug in the compiler? If not, this seems like a major semver-hazard where implementing Drop for a type might break downstream users' code.

Edit:

For a bit of context, in my (embedded) use case `Wrapper` would roughly be a:

```rust
struct FileFormatReader<'a> {
    file: SomeFileHandleWithCloseOnDrop,
    internal_buffer: &'a mut u8,
}
```

`file` has a `Drop` impl in order to close a file and the internal buffer is supplied externally because this is code is supposed to run in a `no_std` context without alloc.
I need to be able to replace the instance of `FileFormatReader` because depending on external factors either no file is open, the state of the current file is mutated (by reading more of its content) or it is replaced by opening another file (using the same statically allocated internal buffer).

As a workaround in my actual code I've replaced the `Option<FileFormatReader>` with a `Option<ManuallyDrop<FileFormatReader>>` for now. The downside is of course that I need to remember to drop the file in the relevant places. That is of course prone to errors.

Comment: This appears to be related to the non-lexical lifetimes borrow-checker. If you use Rust 1.35 and switch between edition 2015 and 2018 you can see the error even without the `Drop` impl.

Comment: also wonder what actual case does this example snippet map to, would you illustrate such a one, where non-atomic mutable borrow needs rebinding in each iteration?

Comment: Adding `Drop` is already considered a major semver change (to my knowledge). There are other places where adding `Drop` prevents compilation, as well; like [moving elements out of a struct](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=57b20b6daf6009c5a305dbbc19ea7610).

Comment: Hm, I guess this behavior of the compiler makes it only slightly worse then because it even affects types without public fields where moving elements out or destructuring the type is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a bug in the compiler?

No.

Without `drop`, the compiler can infer that it is fine to destructure `f` into its parts and that `a` is no longer needed. With `Drop`, however, it has to call the `drop` function at some point, and it does so after the `match` statement.

It is not smart enough to figure out that you only create a new `Wrapper` in the `None` case; for the borrow checker all it sees is that you create a new reference and then call `drop` on an object with an overlapping **lifetime**. The lifetime attached to `f` is **independent** of its content.

This might demonstrate it:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
enum MyEnum<T> {
    Some(T),
    None,
}
impl<T> Drop for MyEnum<T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {}
}

fn main() {
    let mut data = Vec::new();
    data.push(42);

    // The **type** of data_ref carries the lifetime, not the variable itself!
    let mut data_ref = MyEnum::Some(&mut data);
    println!("{:?}", data_ref);

    // The fact that `data_ref` is now `None` does **not** change its lifetime!
    // The compiler must assume that the type is still attached to the lifetime
    // during its `drop` call at the end of the function.
    data_ref = MyEnum::None;
    data.push(69);
}
```

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `data` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:22:5
   |
15 |     let mut data_ref = MyEnum::Some(&mut data);
   |                                     --------- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
22 |     data.push(69);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
23 | }
   | - first borrow might be used here, when `data_ref` is dropped and runs the `Drop` code for type `MyEnum`
```

That's at least my understanding; correct me if I'm wrong.

---

> If not, this seems like a major semver-hazard where implementing Drop for a type might break downstream users' code.

To my knowledge, it is already considered by many that adding `Drop` to a type is semver-major. There are other places where adding `Drop` prevents compilation as well; like [moving elements out of a struct](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/compiler/rustc_error_codes/src/error_codes/E0509.md):

```rust
struct WithoutDrop {
    pub a: String,
}

struct WithDrop {
    pub b: String,
}

impl Drop for WithDrop {
    fn drop(&mut self) {}
}

fn main(){
    let without_drop = WithoutDrop{ a: String::new() };
    let with_drop = WithDrop{ b: String::new() };
    
    // We can move out of objects if they don't implement Drop
    let a = without_drop.a;
    drop(a);
    
    // We can not, however, move out of objects if they do implement Drop
    let b = with_drop.b;
    drop(b);
}
```

```
error[E0509]: cannot move out of type `WithDrop`, which implements the `Drop` trait
  --> src/main.rs:22:13
   |
22 |     let b = with_drop.b;
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^
   |             |
   |             cannot move out of here
   |             move occurs because `with_drop.b` has type `String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   |
help: consider borrowing here
   |
22 |     let b = &with_drop.b;
   |             +
```

Comment: The compiler should be able to see that the value is not dropped, because `match f` moves out of the variable and leaves it uninitialized.

Comment: One thing to note is that `MyEnum` cannot even be destructured in a match because of its drop impl.

Comment: While I appreciate your answer, I think the point of Chayim Friedman still stands.